# sort array based on indices of an object

Tags: javascript

We have this:

```
const cardIndices = {
  'card 1': 0,
  'card 2': 1,
  'card 3': 2,
  'card 4': 3,
  'card 5': 3, // same index just like card 4
};


const allCards = ['card 4', 'card 2', 'card 3', 'card 1', 'card 5'];
```

And we want to sort `allCards` based on `cardIndices`. as you see each card in `cardIndices` have its index which is not unique right ?

The desired result would be:

```
['card 1', 'card 2', 'card 3', 'card 4', 'card 5']
```

Here is what I tried but I think I'm not in a right path:

```
const arr = []
for(let a = 0; a <= allCards; a++) {
    const card = allCards[a];
  if(cardIndices[card] > cardIndices[allCards[a + 1]]) arr.push(card);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const cardIndices = {
  'card 1': 0,
  'card 2': 1,
  'card 3': 2,
  'card 4': 3,
  'card 5': 3,
};


const allCards = ['card 4', 'card 2', 'card 3', 'card 1', 'card 5'];


const sorted = [...allCards].sort((a, b) => cardIndices[a] - cardIndices[b])

console.log(sorted)
```